# How would this C struct be translated into Cobol

Tags: c, cobol

I'm pretty new to Cobol and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to use the structs. What would the C structs below look like when they are converted into Cobol?

These are the structs I have:

```
struct dataT
{
    int m;
};

struct stack
{
    int top;
    struct dataT items[STACKSIZE];
} st;
```

How would this statement be represented in Cobol?

```
st.items[st.top].m
```

Comment: The last line is basically assessing the top of the stack, it get the top value(st.top) and then gets it from the items array holding integers.

Comment: Open Cobol. Im sorry, I wasnt asking how to implement the stack. I was wanted to know syntax. Like how would that struct and that statement look in Cobol so that I can do the rest of the stack my self.

Comment: OK. OpenCOBOL is now GnuCOBOL. If you go here, and ask the question in the `Help getting started` it'll be a much better format for the likely-iterative exploration of your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is very much a stab in the dark since I've never written a line of COBOL before today<sup>1</sup>.  However, after a little [googling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cobol/index.htm)<sup>2</sup> and playing around in [ideone](http://ideone.com/), I think I've at least captured the flavor of what the code would look like, if not the actual solution:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. IDEONE.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

DATA DIVISION.
  WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  01 WS-STACK.
    05 WS-TOP PIC 9 VALUE 0.
    05 WS-ITEMS OCCURS 10 TIMES INDEXED BY I.
      10 WS-M PIC 9 VALUE 0.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    ADD 1 TO WS-TOP.
    MOVE 9 TO WS-M(WS-TOP).
    ADD 1 TO WS-TOP.
    MOVE 8 to WS-M(WS-TOP).
    DISPLAY "WS-STACK :" WS-STACK.
    DISPLAY "WS-TOP :" WS-TOP.
    DISPLAY "WS-ITEMS[WS-STACK.WS-TOP].M :" WS-M(WS-TOP).
    SUBTRACT 1 FROM WS-TOP.
    DISPLAY "WS-TOP :" WS-TOP.
    DISPLAY "WS-ITEMS[WS-STACK.WS-TOP].M :" WS-M(WS-TOP).
    STOP RUN.
```

Yes, size is hardcoded to 10 (don't know how to do symbolic constants in COBOL), and `WS-TOP` and `WS-M` can only store values from 0 to 9.

Needless to say, data types in COBOL and C are very different.  I haven't actually created a new stack type; I've declared a single data items with a couple of sub-items, one of which is a table that can store 10 instances of something called `WS-M`.  This is effectively the same as writing

```
int main( void )
{
  int top = 10;
  int m[10];

  m[--top] = 9;
  m[--top] = 8;

  printf("top = %d\n", top );
  printf("m[%d] = %d", top, m[top] );
  top++;

  printf("top = %d\n", top );
  printf("m[%d] = %d", top, m[top] );
  return 0;
}
```

in C, with the main difference being that I wrote the C code such that the stack grows "downwards" (which is more natural).  As far as I could tell in the ten minutes I spent going through that COBOL tutorial, COBOL does not really have an equivalent to a `struct` type; even though data items can be grouped in a hierarchical manner, you're not creating a new `struct` or record type as such.  If I wanted multiple stacks, I'd have to declare multiple, separate backing stores and index variables.

I think.

I'll have to do a little more reading.

---

<sup>1.  At this point in the day I would rather work on just about *anything* other than the problem in front of me right now, and I've always been curious about how the other half lived.  Also, I'm working on an online banking platform and I know half our backends are written in COBOL, so it wouldn't hurt to take sime time to learn it.



2.  I cannot vouch for the quality of this tutorial; it's the first one I found that seemed reasonably complete and easy to read.</sup>

Comment: @Quentin: bear in mind this was written by a total COBOL noob, so it's not representative of proper COBOL programming.  I'll agree that COBOL ain't all that pretty, but it's not anywhere near as eye-stabby as Perl.

Comment: And I'm not sure this would count as a "stack", or are all arrays in C "on the stack"? To one of your asides, by Standard COBOL does not have symbolic constants. Some compilers do as an Extension, for instance a level-number 78. Combine that with conditional compiler directives (again non-Standard) and I think that would provide what you want there. I thought a stack was different from an array?

Comment: @BillWoodger: See my edit; I fleshed out the C equivalent.  Note that in this case we're using an array to implement a stack data structure.

Comment: @BillWoodger: It's clear enough to a C or C++ programmer.  I'll probably edit this answer again at some point as I learn more.

Comment: If you are developing an interest, you can get yourself an open-source GnuCOBOL compiler, see the SourceForge link under the question.

Comment: And yes, everything in the WORKING-STORAGE is statically defined, GnuCOBOL (for instance) does have BASED storage, but you still make the definition yourself and acquire storage for it. If you want to "model" a structure on another, you'd use a copybook for the structure and COPY ... REPLACING ... to create another definition with different names. You didn't actually use the INDEXED BY that you defined, so that's something to look into :-)

Comment: A quick look at the tutorial reveals a lot of little things which won't compile in the first few parts. This one, http://www.csis.ul.ie/cobol/, should be more robust and less Mainframe-centric.

Comment: Way back when, like 35years ago, I wrote COBOL for a living for an insurance company.  However, thankfully, My career shifted from mainframe COBOL to microprocessors with assembly, pascal, and finally C.   I must admit I have forgotten most of the language and not kept any examples.  So I cannot help you with the details.  however, it has been a interesting walk down memory lane.

Comment: Arrays are sometimes used  in a stack-like manner in COBOL for CICS transactions as "depth" increases and to keep URL-like histories of how that depth was traversed to by a user.  One just needs to be inventive, there is no stack, but there is 'MOD' . and also [:]  for shift up, shift down. So for an array x of size 100 we can PUSH by moving the last 99 elements and updating the first.  Not efficient but maybe easier than using a linked list in shared memory or advancing the subscript/address. I am not a fan of very short variable names for any of this.

Answer (score 0):

You would do that like so:

```
*> Not a symbolic constant, but if it is never referenced as a 
*> target of a move/compute, the compiler should recognize that.
*> and tune for that.

01 Stack-Size      Pic S9(8) comp-4   Value <<some-number>>.

*> The "comp-4" data type is a twos complement integer, S9(8) makes
*> it a 32-bit word.  Depending upon your compiler, you will sometimes
*> see "binary" or "comp-5"

01 My-Stack.
  02 Stack-Top     Pic S9(8) comp-4   Value 0.
  02 Stack-Items   occurs 0 to <<some-maximum-size>> 
                   depending on Stack-Size.
*>-------*
*> This is your data structure, if you made it a copybook, you would have 
*> the similar effect of having the struct def from the C code. You can
*> use the copy/replacing features if you need to make multipule data
*> items with different names. 
*>
    03 Stack-M     Pic S9(8) comp-5.
*>-------*
```

To access the current value on top of the stack:

```
 Move Stack-M (Stack-Top) to where-ever
```

Some helpful paragraphs:

```
 Pop-Stack.
     Move 0 to Stack-M (Stack-Top)
     Subtract 1 from Stack-Top
     Exit.

 Push-Stack.
     Add 1 to Stack-Top
     Move <<whatever value>> to Stack-M (Stack-Top)
     Exit.
```

Comment: COMP-4, where COMP-4 is a binary (not all compilers) is only an integer if not defined with an assumed decimal place. Two's complement is down to implementation, although I don't know of one that isn't. COMP is another binary. All the `depending on` will get is bounds-checking, if available and if turned on. This is only LIFO (OP didn't specify) with a bit of GIGO as there is no checking on the push/pop paragraphs. The pop should not set a zero, otherwise the implication is zero is an invalid actual value. CURR instead of TOP removes possible confusion about why the top is at the bottom...

Comment: TOP is at the bottom?  Stack-Items (TOP) should always have a memory address that is equal to or greater than Stack-Items (1), how is that at the bottom?

Comment: No. I can implement a stack as a Linked List, acquiring storage as I go. Will the memory address always be higher as the stack grows? Maybe, maybe not, and it doesn't matter. Anyway, probably for a C/C++ programmer its not confusing. Just me. Your POP must provide the data from the stack, and both PUSH and POP must do bounds checking (although with a Linked List exceeding the current allocation can just mean "get more storage").